# Socket only emits once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

The code below only emits the data only once. I am not sure it even emits it once as I believe the data is not being sent correctly from frontend(angular 2) to the backend(nodeJs).

frontend code of chat.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
        const sendData = {
          username: this.username,
          message: this.message
        };
        const socket = socketIo('http://localhost:3000');

        socket.emit('chat message', {
          username: 'sendData.username',
          message: sendData.message
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        const messageArea = document.getElementById('output');
        messageArea.innerHTML +="<strong>" + socket.username + "</strong> : " + socket.message + "\n";
        console.log(msg.username + 'lmemons');
      });
    }
```

the code of backend:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('///////////////////////////////');  
        io.emit('chat message', msg.username + ': ' + msg.message);
        console.log('--------------------------');
      });
  });
```

the code runs once which is shown by the console.logs. it only comes out as undefined each time.

I have tried to use the:

> socket.on('chat message', function(msg){...

outside of

> io.on('connection', function(socket){

but it has errors with the socket claiming that it is undefined.

Essentially I want to append the data onto every all connected sockets' text area.

I was using this https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ tutorial for help.

Comment: What exactly comes out as `undefined`?  Which line of code?

Comment: msg.username and msg.message

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "only emits once"? What emits? What exactly happens when you send a message and what should happen that isn't?